# How to overcome the git error `Unknown SSL protocol error in connection`

Tags: git, ssl, poodle-attack

I'm trying to git clone some repository, but then I get the error:

```
$ git clone --recursive https://some-url.git
Cloning into 'project'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://https://some-url.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to
some-url.git:443
```

I've read that the git repositories moved to force the TLS1.0 and no more support SSLv3 communication due to the [POODLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE) vulnerability. But I don't know whether this error message means that my git client only knows to talk SSLv3 and the server denies or that the server only knows to talk SSLv3 and my client denies. If the problem is in my client, how can I configure it to use TLS; on the other hand, if it is the server, how can I resolve?

The error is received on both SourceTree and scm git (console and gui).

Comment: 3 years laters, most Git repository hosting services won't accept TLSv1.0 anymore. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I configure it to use TLS?

Git 2.5 (August 2015) already allows to specify a list of ciphers to use when negotiating SSL connections, with `http.sslCipherList` and `GIT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST`.
(See [Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30442395/6309))

Starting Git 2.6+ (Q3 2015), it will be possible to specify the SSL version explicitly:

> ## `http`: add support for specifying the SSL version

See [commit 01861cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01861cb7a27b948bc0218877311f531f25386691) (14 Aug 2015) by [Elia Pinto (`devzero2000`)](https://github.com/devzero2000).
Helped-by: [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ed070a4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed070a40072f01aa819f114bf6b35edf0f53cab2), 26 Aug 2015)</sup>

```
http.sslVersion
```

> The SSL version to use when negotiating an SSL connection, if you want to force the default.
>   The available and default version depend on whether libcurl was built against NSS or OpenSSL and the particular configuration of the crypto library in use. Internally this sets the '`CURLOPT_SSL_VERSION`' option; see the libcurl documentation for more details on the format of this option and for the ssl version supported.
>   Actually the possible values of this option are:
>
> - sslv2
> - sslv3
> - tlsv1
> - tlsv1.0
> - tlsv1.1
> - tlsv1.2
>
> Can be overridden by the '`GIT_SSL_VERSION`' environment variable.
>   To force git to use libcurl's default ssl version and ignore any explicit `http.sslversion` option, set '`GIT_SSL_VERSION`' to the empty string.

---

The setting above is important since [GitHub now (Feb. 2018) forces disabling weak cryptographic standards](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/).

> On February 8, 2018 we’ll start disabling the following:
>
> - TLSv1/TLSv1.1: This applies to all HTTPS connections, including web, API, and git connections to https://github.com and https://api.github.com.
> - diffie-hellman-group1-sha1: This applies to all SSH connections to github.com
> - diffie-hellman-group14-sha1: This applies to all SSH connections to github.com

---

Git 2.18 (Q2 2018) can now use TLSv1.3:
When built with more recent `cURL`, `GIT_SSL_VERSION` can now specify
"`tlsv1.3`" as its value.

See [commit d81b651](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d81b651f56060038a1547f4beb949122533a8165) (29 Mar 2018) by [Loganaden Velvindron (`loganaden`)](https://github.com/loganaden).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9b59d88](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b59d8869de2fdb63b1ac4cbd68c42b15bda2a19), 11 Apr 2018)</sup>

> ### `http`: allow use of TLS 1.3
>
> Add a tlsv1.3 option to `http.sslVersion` in addition to the existing
>   tlsv1.[012] options.
>   `libcurl` has supported this since 7.52.0.
>
> This requires OpenSSL 1.1.1 with TLS 1.3 enabled or `curl` built with
>   recent versions of NSS or BoringSSL as the TLS backend.

---

With Git 2.21 (Q1 2019), a new "**`http.version`**" configuration variable can be used with recent enough cURL library to **force the version of HTTP used to talk when fetching and pushing**.

See [commit d73019f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d73019feb44b9cb89d9967fb36eae809e8146ace) (09 Nov 2018) by [Force Charlie (`fcharlie`)](https://github.com/fcharlie).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 13d9919](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13d991929810ebfdf6b75d91cdc72561213d548a), 04 Jan 2019)</sup>

> ### http: add support selecting http version
>
> Usually we don't need to set `libcurl` to choose which version of the
>   HTTP protocol to use to communicate with a server.
>   But different versions of `libcurl`, the default value is not the same.

```
CURL >= 7.62.0: CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS
CURL < 7.62: CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1
```

> In order to give users the freedom to control the HTTP version, we need to add a setting to choose which HTTP version to use.

The [`git config` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d73019feb44b9cb89d9967fb36eae809e8146ace/Documentation/config.txt#L1938-L1945) now shows:

```
http.version:
```

> Use the specified HTTP protocol version when communicating with a server.
>   If you want to force the default.
>   The available and default version depend on `libcurl`.
>   Actually the possible values of this option are:
>
> - HTTP/2
> - HTTP/1.1