# SSL error when pushing to Github

Tags: git, github

I have added and committed files on a repo locally but when I push to Github, I get this error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/anandg112/NodeJS-
programs.git/': error:1409441B:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 
alert decrypt error
```

Can someone help me troubleshoot and find the root cause of this error?

I am running git version 2.16.3 and MacOS High Sierra

When I check my .gitconfig file in root. I see this

```
[user]
    email = anand@gmail.com
    name = anandg112
[core]
    editor = vim
[http]
[htttp]
    sslVersion = tlsv1.1
    sslVersion = tlsv1.2
    sslVersion = tlsv1.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS v1 support has been removed by GitHub [since February 2018](https://blog.github.com/2018-02-23-weak-cryptographic-standards-removed/).

Depending on your OS and Git version, make sure you are using an openssl recent enough.

Make sure `curl` and `openssl` are updated (see "[How to upgrade OpenSSL (macOS)](https://medium.com/@katopz/how-to-upgrade-openssl-8d005554401)").

Comment: I am running git version 2.16.3 and MacOS High Sierra.

Comment: @anandg112 what does `curl --version` returns?

Comment: curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0) libcurl/7.52.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2l zlib/1.2.8
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy

Comment: @anandg112 and `openssl version` (no `-` or `--` needed here)?

Comment: @anandg112 basically, you want to upgrade curl and openssl (https://medium.com/@katopz/how-to-upgrade-openssl-8d005554401)

Comment: Hi @vonC, my openSSL version is - OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017 and curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0) . I still get the error when pushing to Github

Comment: @anandg112 Note that tlsv1.3 is only supported in the future Git 2.18: see the last part of https://stackoverflow.com/a/32242297/6309.